# Force the Qt MOC to expand some custom macros?

Tags: c++, qt, c-preprocessor, moc

Is it possible to force the Qt MOC to expand some of my custom preprocessor defines to achieve some kind of 2-pass preprocessing?
E.g.:

```
// MOC macro
@MOC #define add(a, b) (a + b) // Should be expanded by MOC (1st run)

// "Normal" macro
#define sub(a, b) (a - b) // Should be expanded by preprocessor (2nd run)
```

Comment: Do you mean, have something defined only when moc is run? You can wrap it in `#ifdef Q_MOC_RUN`. Not sure what you mean by "2-pass preprocessing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to enable or disable some macros only during the Moc pass, you can test the `Q_MOC_RUN` define as hinted by peppe.

```
#ifdef Q_MOC_RUN
#define MyMacro valueDuringMoc
#else
#define MyMacro defaultValue
#endif
```

If you want to build your own pre-processor rules relying on the same mechanism as MOC, i.e. generating additional C++ code in a .h files included in final build, then you should have a look at that [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119688/macro-expansion-in-moc?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Comment: Thats it (in the link)! Thanks!